# Как разбить массив php на несколько массивов?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте.
после запроса select у меня в переменной $nav содержится массив такого вида

```
Array (
[offline] => Array
    (
        [title] => Offline
        [nav] => 
    )

[404] => Array
    (
        [title] => 404
        [nav] => 
    )

[home] => Array
    (
        [title] => Главная
        [nav] => 
    )

[login] => Array
    (
        [title] => Войти
        [nav] => user
    )

[register] => Array
    (
        [title] => Регистрация
        [nav] => user
    )

[help] => Array
    (
        [title] => Помощь
        [nav] => footer
    )

[advertising] => Array
    (
        [title] => Реклама
        [nav] => footer
    )

[jobs] => Array
    (
        [title] => Вакансии
        [nav] => footer
    )

[team] => Array
    (
        [title] => Команда
        [nav] => footer
    )

[lessons] => Array
    (
        [title] => Уроки
        [nav] => training
    )

[books] => Array
    (
        [title] => Книги
        [nav] => training
    )

[video] => Array
    (
        [title] => Видео
        [nav] => training
    )

[projects] => Array
    (
        [title] => Проекты
        [nav] => work
    )

[news] => Array
    (
        [title] => Новости
        [nav] => main
    )

[forum] => Array
    (
        [title] => Форум
        [nav] => main
    )

[store] => Array
    (
        [title] => Магазин
        [nav] => main
    )

[doc] => Array
    (
        [title] => Справочник
        [nav] => main
    )

[blog] => Array
    (
        [title] => Блог
        [nav] => 
    )

[tools] => Array
    (
        [title] => Инструменты
        [nav] => 
    )

[add] => Array
    (
        [title] => Публикации
        [nav] => 
    )

[order] => Array
    (
        [title] => Заказы
        [nav] => 
    )

[templates] => Array
    (
        [title] => HTML шаблоны
        [nav] => download
    )

[psd] => Array
    (
        [title] => PSD исходники
        [nav] => download
    )

[fonts] => Array
    (
        [title] => Веб шрифты
        [nav] => download
    )

[plugins] => Array
    (
        [title] => Javascript плагины
        [nav] => download
    )

[textures] => Array
    (
        [title] => Текстуры
        [nav] => download
    )

[images] => Array
    (
        [title] => Изображения
        [nav] => download
    )

[software] => Array
    (
        [title] => Программы
        [nav] => download
    )

[services] => Array
    (
        [title] => Сервисы
        [nav] => info
    )

[hosting] => Array
    (
        [title] => Хостинг
        [nav] => info
    )

[cms] => Array
    (
        [title] => CMS системы
        [nav] => info
    )

[users] => Array
    (
        [title] => Пользователи
        [nav] => 
    )

[feedback] => Array
    (
        [title] => Служба поддержки
        [nav] => 
    )

[studio] => Array
    (
        [title] => Студия
        [nav] => 
    )
)
```

как Вы можете заметить значение поля [nav] повторяется, это сделано для разных меню

Вопрос:
как разбить этот массив на отдельные массивы?
например у меня есть 4 совпадения со значением footer, та вот 4 эти поля нужно вынести в отдельную переменную, например $nav_footer

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: мне это нужно для вывода нескольких меню, если сейчас пройтись в цикле foreach получу одно большое меню, а мне нужно разбить на несколько меню,

Comment: А вы в цикл вставьте условия и формируйте несколько меню разом, а потом отправляйте их на вывод в нужных местах шаблона/страницы.

Comment: в этом собственно и заключается вопрос. как?

Comment: Мы же ваш код не видели, чтобы ответить вам как его переделать. Покажите свой текущий код, который сейчас формирует меню у вас.

Comment: <? if (!empty($nav)): foreach ($nav as $item): ?>
    <li><a href="<?=Config::HOME_URL_SEPARATOR.$item['name']?>"><?=$item['title']?></a></li>
<? endforeach; endif; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Обойдите свое меню, сгруппируйте элементы по ключам и воспользуйтесь функцией `extract`, чтобы  создать соответствующие переменные.

```
$menuData = [.
    'offline' => ['title' => "Offline",  'nav' => null],
    '404'     => ['title' => "404",      'nav' => null],
    'home'    => ['title' => "Главная",  'nav' => null],
    'login'   => ['title' => "Войти",    'nav' => "user"],
    'register'=> ['title' => "Регистрация",'nav' => "user"],
    'help'    => ['title' => "Помощь",   'nav' => "footer"],
    'advertising' => ['title' => "Реклама",'nav' => "footer"],
    'jobs'    => ['title' => "Вакансии", 'nav' => "footer"],
    'team'    => ['title' => "Команда",  'nav' => "footer"],
];

$data = [];
foreach($menuData as $k => $md){
    $mkey = "nav".(empty($md['nav']) ? "" : "_".$md['nav']);
    $data[$mkey][$k] = ['title' => $md['title']];
}

extract($data);

print_r($nav_footer);
```

в выводе этой переменной получите 4 элемента.

если не пользоваться `extract()`, то просто изначально записать в переменные, не используя доп. массив:

```
foreach($menuData as $k => $md){
    ${$mkey}[$k] = ['title' => $md['title']];
}
```

Я правда не вижу особого смысла в разделении этого массива на отдельные переменные, и, как кажется, достаточно бы было простой группировки (`print_r($data)` и дальнейшего использования `$data['nav_footer']` и т.п.).